# transform: rotate in firefox needs different value than webkit?

Tags: css, firefox, svg

I have an SVG that's rotated -45deg, which looks the way I want it to in Chrome and Safari, but when I look at it in Firefox the SVG isn't rotated correctly - I have to set the value to -90deg for it to look the same. I've tried with and without vendor prefixes. Here's the site it's on for an example (svg in question is the umbrella): http://agentem.github.io/CoverMe/

```
svg {
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    margin-left: 3%;
    fill:#FFF;
}
```

Comment: The behaviour in Firefox should be the same as in Chrome. I've opened your website in different Firefox versions and it works as expected so probably the problem isn't related to the browser.

Comment: Looks fine for me in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Can't reproduce this issue either rotate -45deg looks the same

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same issue. I ended up working around it by doing this:

```
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

The `-moz-transform` property will only be understood by Firefox.

Modern Firefox can understand regular `transform` so `-moz-transform` needs to come second.

Answer (score 0):

```
transform: none
transform: matrix(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0)
transform: translate(12px, 50%)
transform: translateX(2em)
transform: translateY(3in)
transform: scale(2, 0.5)
transform: scaleX(2)
transform: scaleY(0.5)
transform: rotate(0.5turn)
transform: skewX(30deg)
transform: skewY(1.07rad)
transform: matrix3d(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0)
transform: translate3d(12px, 50%, 3em)
transform: translateZ(2px)
transform: scale3d(2.5, 1.2, 0.3)
transform: scaleZ(0.3)
transform: rotate3d(1, 2.0, 3.0, 10deg)
transform: rotateX(10deg)
transform: rotateY(10deg)
transform: rotateZ(10deg)
transform: perspective(17px)

transform: translateX(10px) rotate(10deg) translateY(5px)
```

For example rotate 30deg:

```
-webkit-transform: translate(100px) rotate(20deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 60% 100%;

    -o-transform:translate(100px) rotate(20deg); 
    -o-transform-origin:60% 100%;

    transform: translate(100px) rotate(20deg);
    transform-origin: 60% 100%;
```

For example see

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Create Rotate css3 code with

http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transform.html